# How to check the ifIndex on a Fortigate 1500D?

Tags: firewall, fortigate, fortinet

What is the exact command to check the port ifIndex that is used by SNMP to reflect trap at SNMP host at 1500D Fortigate?

The command `diagnose sys device list root` displays the index which isn't unique for every port.

The command `diagnose hardware  deviceinfo nic  Portno` also displays various hardware parameters related to port but not ifIndex.

How can I check the ifIndex on a Fortigate 1500D device?

```
Version: FortiGate-1500D v5.4.4,build1117,170209
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should show you the snmp-index for each interface on the Fortigate. You can also modify this field if you so choose.

```
# config system interface
(interface) # show
```

Comment: @Ron Thanks. I  saw SNMP index using this.

Answer (score 0):

```
diagnose sys device list root
```

or

```
diagnose sys device list VDOM
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Please check carefully it gives index that is repeated for more than a port

Comment: You're correct - apparently, an unused port can have the same index as a used one. I don't think there's a clear solution to this ambiguity, I'd contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

diagnose netlink interface list

It will show you the index references for the interfaces.

Example:

***if=port1*** family=00 type=1 ***index=10*** mtu=1500 link=0 master=0
ref=8 state=start present flags=up broadcast run promsic multicast

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `diag ip route list`, where the "dev" is same "index"

```
tab=255 vf=0 scope=254 type=2 proto=2 prio=0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0->192.168.1.100/32 pref=192.168.1.100 gwy=0.0.0.0 dev=12(port10)
tab=255 vf=0 scope=253 type=3 proto=2 prio=0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0->192.168.1.255/32 pref=192.168.1.100 gwy=0.0.0.0 dev=12(port10)
tab=255 vf=0 scope=253 type=3 proto=2 prio=0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0->192.168.2.0/32 pref=192.168.2.127 gwy=0.0.0.0 dev=3(port1)
tab=255 vf=0 scope=254 type=2 proto=2 prio=0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0->192.168.2.127/32 pref=192.168.2.127 gwy=0.0.0.0 dev=3(port1)
tab=255 vf=0 scope=253 type=3 proto=2 prio=0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0/0->192.168.2.255/32 pref=192.168.2.127 gwy=0.0.0.0 dev=3(port1)
```